# From a MySQL table select one or more rows and update columns from each one

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, updates

I have a table with pre-existing giveaway codes and I need to select one or more rows and then update three columns of each row with personal identification, customer code, and "reserved" status. This to reserve each row until receiving a response from our client's API.

The table look like this:

```
code               identification    customer_code    status
-----------------------------------------------------------------
81Ow3tCs1nNwxKu    --                --               available
I1NdH9F22S7RhU3    --                --               available
Xc942LWe8Z6nt8x    --                --               available
zcLMRO8kSeM7S06    --                --               available
K94erORvzSsU0ik    --                --               available
```

Tried with this but got an error:

```
UPDATE promo_codes 
SET 
    identification='12345',
    customer_code='67890',
    status='reserved' 
FROM 
(SELECT code FROM promo_codes WHERE status='available' LIMIT 2);
```

Then I tried with REPLACE INTO but also with error:

```
REPLACE INTO promo_codes(identification,customer_code,status)
VALUES('12345','67890','reserved')
WHERE
(SELECT code FROM promo_codes WHERE status='available' LIMIT 2);
```

I do not know what else to do. Could someone give me an idea?
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little rewriting and you code works

You should consider adding a ORDER BY RAND() , because a LIMIT without an order is quite meaningless

> ```
> CREATE TABLE promo_codes  (
>   `code` VARCHAR(15),
>   `identification` VARCHAR(20),
>   `customer_code` VARCHAR(20),
>   `status` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO promo_codes 
>   (`code`, `identification`, `customer_code`, `status`)
> VALUES
>   ('81Ow3tCs1nNwxKu', '--', '--', 'available'),
>   ('I1NdH9F22S7RhU3', '--', '--', 'available'),
>   ('Xc942LWe8Z6nt8x', '--', '--', 'available'),
>   ('zcLMRO8kSeM7S06', '--', '--', 'available'),
>   ('K94erORvzSsU0ik', '--', '--', 'available');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE promo_codes 
> SET 
>     identification='12345',
>     customer_code='67890',
>     status='reserved' 
> WHERE status='available' LIMIT 2;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM promo_codes
> ```
>
> ```
> code            | identification | customer_code | status   
> :-------------- | :------------- | :------------ | :--------
> 81Ow3tCs1nNwxKu | 12345          | 67890         | reserved 
> I1NdH9F22S7RhU3 | 12345          | 67890         | reserved 
> Xc942LWe8Z6nt8x | --             | --            | available
> zcLMRO8kSeM7S06 | --             | --            | available
> K94erORvzSsU0ik | --             | --            | available
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d659c510718e8dd00cc267e7591a0246)*